# Nodejs child process was closed by sigterm ,and it works if I execute it in command window, how to stay alive?

Tags: node.js, xcode

I wanna execute command like building IOS with xcode

```
    var cp = require("child_process");
    var cmd="xcodebuild archive -project xx.xcodeproj -scheme xxx -archivePath ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/xxx-ios.xcarchive";
    var o = cp.exec(cmd, execOptions, {
        stdio: "inherit"
    });
    o.stdout.on("data", function (chunk) {
        if (!chunk || chunk.trim() === "" || chunk.trim().indexOf("UP-TO-DATE") != -1) return;
        else {
            console.info(chunk.trim().toString());
        }
    });
    o.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
        console.info(data);
    });
    o.on("close", function (code,signal) {
        if (code === 1) {
            console.info(cmd+ "close code : " + code);
            reject(false);
        } else {
            console.info(cmd+ "close code : " + code);
            resolve(true);
        }
    });

    o.on("exit", (code) => {
        console.info(cmd+ "exit code : " + code);
    });
```

Basically it works if I give simple commands, but I wanna build ios via xCode, process was closed with code null and signal "SIGTERM", I also add maxBuffer option,and It does not work still, how do I get it work?

Child Process of nodejs https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Answer (score 2):

Oh, No answer at all, so I am gonna add my solution to helper others.
My issue is it includes too many output words there, and It reached max buffer, so I just grab less output by following command:
var cmd="xcodebuild archive -project xx.xcodeproj -scheme xxx -archivePath ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/xxx-ios.xcarchive | egrep -w -i -C 2 "(ARCHIVE|error)"